# Parsed JSON data not being printed to the console

Tags: ios

I have written a simple code that takes specific data from a News API and prints it to the console.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    let url = URL(string: "https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=bbc-news&sortBy=top&apiKey=af5f94cdf07e42ee877a3f2c2199d097")

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) {(data, response, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print("Error")
        }
        else {
            if let content = data {
                do {
                    let myJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as AnyObject
                    if let articles = myJson["articles"] as? NSDictionary {
                        if let title = articles["title"] {
                            print(title)
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch {}
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

However, strangely, this returns no errors AND doesn't print the desired "title" to the console either. Why is this?

Comment: Are you loading the view? That code works just fine in a playground.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to swift - what do you mean by loading the view? I have not made any changes to the storyboard and this code is under the viewDidLoad() function.

Comment: `viewDidLoad()` is called when a view actually loads. You have to run the app and load the view.

Comment: I have tried running the app on both the simulator and my phone, but the console still shows nothing

Comment: The code is clearly not executing then. Are you loading the view or not?

Comment: I believe the view is loading - all I have in the viewcontroller is a label which I added using the storyboard builder, and the label does appear when I run the app.

Comment: Add breakpoints to the first line in `viewDidLoad()` and see if it gets hit? Other possibility is that Xcode isn't displaying the console data properly, or the app isn't attached to the debugger.

Comment: I added a breakpoint to the line super.viewDidLoad() and the label no longer appears when I run the app (I am assuming the view is now not loading) and "(11db) appears in the console.

Comment: Ok, then put a breakpoint inside the closure of the API call and use step-through to get to it.

Comment: Stepped in, over, out - no luck

Comment: I'd start a new Xcode project — single view application — and see if that works?

Comment: Ok - when you said the code works fine in a playground, was the console showing the data?

Comment: Yes — http://d.pr/i/UIH0

Comment: That's strange, in my playground, I get the same top and bottom lines in the console, but not the middle line with the JSON data

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem would be the App Transport Security.

Make sure you set up these keys in your plist file.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Comment: I have added those keys in my plist file, but the same thing occurs. Isn't the AllowsArbitraryLoads key only required for http urls only? The url I am using is https